Make button active depending on local database value
I'm creating a card database system, and wanting to pull data from a local database and make a button active if the username and card_rarity_id exist, then the related condition and edition buttons should get highlighted. As shown in this pic
The code I have is as follows:
app.py
@app.route('/set_list/<set_code>')
@login_required
def set_list(set_code):
    card_sets = get_card_sets()
    selected_set = next((s for s in card_sets if s['set_code'] == set_code), None)

    if not selected_set:
        return render_template('set_not_found.html', set_code=set_code)

    matching_cards = get_cards_by_set(set_code)

    for card in matching_cards:
        card['sanitized_name'] = sanitize_filename_set(card['card_name'])

    return render_template('set_list.html', selected_set=selected_set, matching_cards=matching_cards)

set_list.html
<div class="btn-group btn-group-toggle" data-toggle="buttons" style="margin-top: 10px;">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-primary edition-button" name="card_edition" value="1ST"
        data-edition="1ST" {% if user_card_data and user_card_data.card_edition=="1ST" %} class="active" {% endif
        %}>1ST</button>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-secondary edition-button" name="card_edition" value="UNL"
        data-edition="UNL" {% if user_card_data and user_card_data.card_edition=="UNL" %} class="active" {% endif
        %}>UNL</button>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-success edition-button" name="card_edition" value="LIM"
        data-edition="LIM" {% if user_card_data and user_card_data.card_edition=="LIM" %} class="active" {% endif
        %}>LIM</button>
</div>


<div class="btn-group btn-group-toggle" data-toggle="buttons" style="margin-top: 10px;">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-info condition-button" name="card_condition" value="NM"
        data-condition="NM" {% if user_card_data and user_card_data.card_condition=="NM" %} class="active" {% endif
        %}>NM</button>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-warning condition-button" name="card_condition" value="EXC"
        data-condition="EXC" {% if user_card_data and user_card_data.card_condition=="EXC" %} class="active" {% endif
        %}>EXC</button>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-danger condition-button" name="card_condition" value="GD"
        data-condition="GD" {% if user_card_data and user_card_data.card_condition=="GD" %} class="active" {% endif
        %}>GD</button>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-dark condition-button" name="card_condition" value="PL"
        data-condition="PL" {% if user_card_data and user_card_data.card_condition=="PL" %} class="active" {% endif
        %}>PL</button>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-secondary condition-button" name="card_condition" value="PO"
        data-condition="PO" {% if user_card_data and user_card_data.card_condition=="PO" %} class="active" {% endif
        %}>PO</button>
</div>
                                

I have tried a few different things, but none have worked. Appreciate all the help!
I tried this previously, but it didn't work:
<div class="btn-group btn-group-toggle" data-toggle="buttons" style="margin-top: 10px;">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-primary edition-button {% if user_card_data and user_card_data.card_edition == '1ST' %}active{% endif %}" name="card_edition" value="1ST" data-edition="1ST">1ST</button>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-secondary edition-button {% if user_card_data and user_card_data.card_edition == 'UNL' %}active{% endif %}" name="card_edition" value="UNL" data-edition="UNL">UNL</button>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-success edition-button {% if user_card_data and user_card_data.card_edition == 'LIM' %}active{% endif %}" name="card_edition" value="LIM" data-edition="LIM">LIM</button>
</div>

<div class="btn-group btn-group-toggle" data-toggle="buttons" style="margin-top: 10px;">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-info condition-button {% if user_card_data and user_card_data.card_condition == 'NM' %}active{% endif %}" name="card_condition" value="NM" data-condition="NM">NM</button>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-warning condition-button {% if user_card_data and user_card_data.card_condition == 'EXC' %}active{% endif %}" name="card_condition" value="EXC" data-condition="EXC">EXC</button>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-danger condition-button {% if user_card_data and user_card_data.card_condition == 'GD' %}active{% endif %}" name="card_condition" value="GD" data-condition="GD">GD</button>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-dark condition-button {% if user_card_data and user_card_data.card_condition == 'PL' %}active{% endif %}" name="card_condition" value="PL" data-condition="PL">PL</button>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-secondary condition-button {% if user_card_data and user_card_data.card_condition == 'PO' %}active{% endif %}" name="card_condition" value="PO" data-condition="PO">PO</button>
</div>

